My Ugreen bluetooth CM748 This device is working in Windows but not in Ubuntu
I recently added Ugreen CM748 5.4 Bluetooth device Inside this bluetooth use BR8654A02 chipset. It runs properly on Windows, but in Ubuntu it shows but does not turn on.

More information about Bluetooth device: https://g.co/gemini/share/21e34e5c7d21
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 33fa:0010  USB2.0-BT is my Bluetooth device. It shows, but it does not turn on.
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 30fa:0300  USB Optical Mouse 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL88x2bu [AC1200 Techkey]
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 33fa:0010  USB2.0-BT
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b071 Chi
cony Electronics Co., Ltd 2.0M UVC Webcam / CNF7129
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Please help me to troubleshoot this problem.
I useign this ubuntu version: OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86
enter image description here

The gemini information isn't very useful, and LLMs are often unreliable. https://www.ugreen.com/products/ugreen-usb-bluetooth-5-3-adapter-for-pc?_pos=5&_sid=97a228df5&_ss=r seems to be the model  and https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=404582 indicates some BT 5.3 chipsets don't have kernel support yet. Working out the chipset and compiling appropriate drivers might work

The manufacturer doesn't want to reveal many details about this device as it may give competition an advantage
